# Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in Zend Framework + Wamp

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

I have following code :

in **application.ini**

```
cache.default.adapter = "memcached"
cache.default.params.host = "localhost"
cache.default.params.port = "11211"
```

in **Bootstrap.php**

```
$cache = new Memcache();        
$cache->connect($cache_params['host'], $cache_params['port']);
Zend_Registry::set("cache", $cache);
```

and also I am having memcache installed on my machine by putting `php_memcache.dll` in `wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext` and also `extension=php_memcache.dll` in php.ini

But still I am getting the following error :

**( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in \wamp\www\projectname\application\Bootstrap.php on line 160**

I have gone through google but still not able to solved the problem. What is the problem why it's not connecting to the memcache.

Comment: If you setup a `phpinfo()` page is the Memcache extension listed there?

Comment: @Tim Fountain : No, there is no memcache extension listed

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cache your database?

You want to use Zend_Cache.

(From: http://zendcoding.com/how-to-use-memcached-in-the-zend-framework)

```
$frontendOpts = array(
    'caching' => true,
    'lifetime' => 1800, //how long in seconds to keep the cache for.
    'automatic_serialization' => true //In order to store objects and arrays, Zend must first serialize data into a string. If this parameter is set to ‘true‘, this serialization will happen on the fly and behind the scenes.
);

$backendOpts = array(
    'servers' =>array(
        array(
        'host'   => $cache_params['host'],
        'port'   => $cache_params['port'],
        'weight' => 1
        )
    ),
    'compression' => false
);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', $frontendOpts, $backendOpts);
```

This link also demonstrates how to load and update the cache, and how to make it accessible from everywhere in your application. A good read, to be sure.

Comment: Actually I shifted my OS from ubuntu to windows. In ubuntu it was working perfectly but why its showing problem in windows. I installed memcache in windows by referencing this link : http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine

Answer (score 0):

Your setting is memcached

`cache.default.adapter = "memcached"`

but you want to use memcache

`$cache = new Memcache();`

**Try this example**

```html
<?php
$mc = new Memcached('mc');
$mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, true);
if (!count($mc->getServerList())) {
    $mc->addServers(array(
        array('127.0.0.1',11211),
        array('127.0.0.1',11211),
    ));
}
$key = 'mykey';
$mc->add($key,'test for memcached not memcache');
$val = $mc->get($key);
echo $val;


?>
```